# What is the fastest way to sort these n^2 numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Given a number 'n', I want to return a sorted array of n^2 numbers containing all the values of k1*k2 where k1 and k2 can range from 1 to n.

For example for n=2 it would return : {1,2,2,4}.(the number are basically 1*1,1*2,2*1,2*2).

and for n=3 it would return : {1,2,2,3,3,4,6,6,9}.

(the numbers being : 1*1, 2*1, 1*2, 2*2, 3*1, 1*3, 3*2, 2*3, 3*3)

I tried it using sort function from c++ standard library, but I was wondering if it could be further optimized.

Comment: I'm not a pro sorter but maybe you can look at those visualizations: https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms I hope this helps

Comment: is it an excersize? programming contest?

Comment: @Murf Hi! we can obviously do it using some sorting algorithm, but I think there could be some situation specific solution here, that I am unable to figure out.

Comment: If you can cheaply decompose each number into its prime factors, you can do it in one pass.

Comment: @Caleth As far as I'm aware. no efficient algorithm for prime factorization exists (though given the constraints of this problem, it may be possible to do so in this context).

Comment: @Pandatyr Yes, I think the answer to this is going to boil down to "naively generate the sequence then stable sort it"

Comment: @Caleth how would I do it in one pass, assuming that i have prime factors of each number?

Comment: @Caleth That's what I had in mind. A native counting approach would work but would definitely require superlinear storage, though given that the result has quadratic complexity anyways I'm not sure if this matters too much.

Comment: for each `1 < number < n^2`, find the prime factors of number. if they are all < n, output 2 * len(permutations(factors)) copies of number

Comment: You can use Pascal's triangle to find the count of permutations

Comment: This problem can nicely be visualized: consider all pairs `k1,k2` as points; they form a `k*k` square grid. Now consider rectangles with the lower left corner in the origin `0,0` and the top right corner in each respective point `k1,k2`. These rectangles have sizes `k1*k2`, so you want to sort these rectangles by size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all, you get `n^2` entries, the largest of which will be `n^2`, and of the possible value range, only a tiny amount of values is used for large `n`. So, I'd suggest a counting approach:

1. Initialize an array `counts[]` of size `n^2` with zeros.
2. Iterate through your array of values `values[]`, and do `counts[values[i]-1]++`.
3. Reinitialize the `values` array by iterating through the `counts` array, dropping as many values of `i+1` into the `values` array as `counts[i]` gives you.

That's all. It's `O(n^2)`, so you'll hardly find a more performant solution.

Comment: It's O(n^2), if you use a consistent definition for `n`

Comment: Isn't this prohibitively expensive for "large n?" I suppose it depends on what you mean by "large." When n is one million, you're talking about allocating an array of a trillion items. I'd say that this algorithm is workable for "small to medium n."

Comment: @JimMischel Since the OP wants the function to return an array of size `n^2` anyway, there's no point in optimizing the space consumption, the space overhead of my sketched algorithm is just a factor of two. If the goal were to have a generator for the resulting number sequence, that would be a very different story. In that case, the first optimization that springs to mind is to replace the `count` array by an `std::unordered_map<int, int>` because of its sparseness at the high end. But that's overkill if the output is the full array anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
vector<int> count(n*n+1);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    for (int j = 1; j <= n; ++j)
        ++count[i*j];
for (int i = 1; i <= n*n; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < count[i]; ++j)
        cout << i << " ";
```

This is in essence the O(n*n) solution as described in cmaster's answer.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.